# Abrir modal de confirmacion antes de enviar

Tags: javascript, html5

**Quiero abrir un modal para confirmar si esta seguro de realizar la accion, pero se envia directamente como lo soluciono?**

tengo varios links href='envaluacion/primera' la cadena primera y la palabra primera va cambiando es dinamico

```js
$('.envios').click(function() {

  swal({
      title: "Aviso",
      text: "Esta seguro que desea salir?",
      type: "warning",
      showCancelButton: true,
      confirmButtonClass: "btn-danger",
      confirmButtonText: "Salir",
      cancelButtonText: "Cancelar",
      closeOnConfirm: false,
      closeOnCancel: false
    },
    function(isConfirm) {
      if (isConfirm) {
        location.href = "http://www.pagina1.com";
      } else {
        swal("Cancelado", "Usted esta aqui", "error");
      }
    });

});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.css" media="screen" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/sweetalert/1.1.3/sweetalert.min.js"></script>

<a href='envaluacion/primera' class="envios">Irse
```

Comment: En la documentación está un ejemplo de esto. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Debe usar promesas como está en la [documentación](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#using-promises)  , antes de esto deberá agregar el [script correcto *(cdn)*](https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/#installation) a su documento.

Si desea obtener el `href` de su link clickeado, simplemente acceda a `this.href` ya que `this` hará referencia al tag `<a>`

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
```

```js
$(function() {
 $('.envios').click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  swal({
   title: "Aviso",
   text: "Está seguro que desea salir ? ",
   icon: "warning",
   buttons: true,
   dangerMode: true,
  })
  .then((willDelete) => {
   if (willDelete) {
            //Mensaje Opcional
            swal("Usted será redireccionado", {
             icon: "success",
            });
            console.log(this.href);
            // redirección location.href = this.href
        } else {
         swal("Canceceló la acción");
        }
    });
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/sweetalert/dist/sweetalert.min.js"></script>
<a href='envaluacion/primera' class="envios">Irse</a>
<a href='envaluacion/segunda' class="envios">Irse a Otra</a>
```

Comment: en mi caso tengo valores en href='#' que quiero enviar por get

Comment: en realidad tengo varios links href='envaluacion/primera' la cadena primera y la palabra primera va cambiando es dinamico

Comment: @hubman si desea obtener el href , añadí la actualización a mi respuesta 3:)

Comment: una maravilla, asunto solucionado gracias!!!

Comment: para en entre al servidor hace falta descomentar la redireccion?

Comment: @hubman abrió una pregunta,lo cuál  es mejor... vamos a resolver las dudas ahí.